# Fantasy Book Series - travel through Dante's 9 circles

Tags: story-identification, books

Series was from late '80s - early '90s about a guy who ends up in a weird Dante 9 circles of hell and teams up with an ancestor from the British army and the granddaughter of Grace Slick. They work their way through the 9 circles to get back home - think the character's name was "Newville", maybe - I think author may have had a French or Italian name maybe.

Comment: It sounds vaguely like Philip Jose Farmer's The Dungeon series. I don't recall any mention of Grace Slick though.

Comment: I do believe this is the series now that I see the books - it was a long time ago so the grace slick memory could easily be erroneous, maybe just a personal theory that was never priven or disproven as i didn'tfinishthe series.   Thanks so much - I am ordering the books now

Comment: @Ksaid - when you receive the books and confirm that this is the correct answer, could you please let us know? (By coming back and accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As verified by Ksaid in a comment to the question, this is Philip Jose Farmer's "The Dungeon" series, six books none of which was actually written by Farmer.